# Importing startapp in android studio

Tags: android, startapp

I have a problem when I try to import:

```
android.view.View
StartAppAd
StartAppSDK
```

When I import these, they are marked as inactive (grey color).

I use [this guide](http://www.karantips.com/p/startapp-ads-in-android-studio.html), but the error `cannot resolve symbol...` persists.

I switched to autocomplete for optimized importing. There is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This looks like you are missing the dependencies for `startapp` Have you added them in your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

Create libs folder inside android module, may be already present there. Keep **StartAppInApp-3.5.6.jar** inside libs folder and add dependency section inside build.gradle of android module.

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

Refresh gradle dependency.